# extract and align rows based on column values

Tags: r, formatting

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID      Value   ID2     Value2
26390   1.1     26400   11.1
26400   2.4     26405   11.8
26405   15.6    26410   11.6
26410   0       26420   11.9
26420   0       26430   3.3
26440   0       26455   5.9
```

What I want to do is pull out and align the Value and Value2 data for the IDs that match up.  For example, this is what I'd like to get back from the above:

```
ID      Value   ID2     Value2
26400   2.4     26400   11.1
26405   15.6    26405   11.8
26410   0       26410   11.6
26420   0       26420   11.9
```

Any thoughts on how to do this in R?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `merge()`. Assuming your data is `dat`:

```
dat.align <- merge(dat[,1:2], dat[,3:4], by.x = "ID", by.y = "ID2")
dat.align
#      ID Value Value2
# 1 26400   2.4   11.1
# 2 26405  15.6   11.8
# 3 26410   0.0   11.6
# 4 26420   0.0   11.9
```

Comment: No worries - I just wish all questions were asked as clearly as yours!